# Android menu item list navigation

Tags: android, menu

I need help please could someone help me with switch and case...

I have 3 item in action bar item1, item2, item3 and i have 3 activity item1Activity.java, item2Activity, item2Activity.. I want to call those activity from menu when its item selected..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


/** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
String[] actions = new String[] {
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3"
};
protected int position;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);


    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

            switch (itemPosition) {
            case 1:
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Item1Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            case 2:
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Item2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
                }

                }
        };

    /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);  

}
```

}

Comment: So, what seem to be the problem?

Comment: Try using getApplicationContext() instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: thanks for your reply dear Mohamed, it works only Item2Activity.class when i cheese item3 it will crash...

Answer (score 0):

> Use MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext()

Activity is child of Context

Comment: thanks for your help. but when i use MainActivity it will crash